# Excel VBA AutoFill Destination Error on range of cells

Tags: excel, vba

Can't seem to figure out why there's an error on the fourth line here :

`LastCol = Range("A2").End(xlToRight).Column`

`LastRow = Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row`

`Range(Cells(3, LastCol + 1), Cells(3, LastCol + 2)).Select`

`Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(3, LastCol + 1), Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 2))`

There are no errors on previous lines. The code line that needs to be debugged is the fourth one. Can't seem to find the issue here since it's just asking for an autofill on a valid range of cells.

Comment: Do you want auto filling starting on the next column after the first blank one up to the second one? If so, what does `LastRow` return? If not, please explain **in words** what you try accomplishing from the column to be processed point of view. Does your code select **the correct range to be processed**?

Comment: Has changing `Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 1)` to `Cells(LastRow, LastCol + 2)` fixed your issue?

Comment: @VBasic2008, nope, it doesn't. I've checked that the cells returned the right values while debugging. I ran it again, and somehow that line worked this time (not sure why), but i ran into the same error code again on a different line.

Comment: For this different line, I followed @FaneDuru's advice and looked at the issue, and indeed it's out of the range initially posted due to the same code applied on different sets of data. I've edited the range accordingly, so far it's working.